# Can not add/delete/edit record in Oracle SQL Deverloper connect to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I love Oracle SQL Developer and not a big fan of PgAdmin. I am trying to connect to the Postgresql from Oracle SQL Developer. And i am success.

However, i am not able to add/delete/edit any record.

I am using third party JDBC Driver: postgresql-42.2.23.jar

any suggestion ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write the SQL (INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE) to do that in the SQL worksheet.

If you want to browse a table and 'live edit' records in the GUI, you'll need to be connected to an Oracle Database.

Comment: so there is no way i can insert update delete in the GUI of Oracle SQL Developer that connect to Postgresql. :((((( sad.

Comment: unless you count the editor where you can run SQL as part of the GUI, then no